# Xcode 4 ruby syntax coloring for rake files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode4, rake

Has anyone figured out a way to have Xcode4 use syntax coloring for Ruby on a .rake file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will stick as automatic coloring, but to color rake files as ruby, open the rake file then open File attributes inspector (Cmd+Alt+1). In the "File type" drop down choose "Ruby script".

Comment: Thanks that was a good suggestion but doesn't seem to be doing anything for syntax coloring.